# How to use wildcard in visual basic dot net

Tags: vb.net

This code works for me but I do not know why. Can anyone explain this code?

```
String.Format("'{0}%' LIKE '{1}%'", column_name, textbox1.text);
```

Comment: What inputs are you giving it? What output do you get? And then, importantly, what are you doing with that result.

Comment: Textbox1.text is null means i want to display all the null values and not null values

Comment: A statement like this would format the WHERE clause of a SQL statement.  It is **very** dangerous, you should never write code like this.  Google "Little Bobby Tables".

Comment: No i want to filter many columns separately or two columns combine so where clause cannot be satisfied for me

Comment: @Nikil There are ways to achieve what you want, but at the moment we cannot tell what it is that you want because your question is simply unclear. Give us more context - show us the set of columns and show us enough that we can reproduce your situation. Only then can we help you!

Answer (score 1):

`String.Format` replaces `{n}` in its first parameter with `n`-th following parameter. Thus, it will replace `{0}` with the value of `column_name` and `{1}` with the value of `textbox1.text`, so if `column_name` is `"name"` and `textbox1.text` is "Joe", the result will be `'Jo%' LIKE 'Joe%'`. I am not 100% convinced that this is what you want though. Also, regarding your title - none of this is a wildcard in VB.Net (although it does gain the wildcard semantics if you pass it to an SQL database).

Comment: I think your suggestions is correct but i cannot understand

Comment: @Nikil `column_name` and `textbox1.text` are two string variables. `String.Format` is a method. When the method is executed it checks the first parameter for expressions like `{0}` or `{1}` and so on. If it finds such an expression it takes the string value in the second, third and so on parameter and exchanges `{...}` with this value. Nothing more. So `String.Format("{0}", "Hello World") results in the string `Hello World`. It's hard to make it any clearer.